# Using requirejs with dojo 1.9.1

Tags: dojo, requirejs, dojox.charting

Can anybody provide me with a simple example of how to use requirejs to load dojo modules?

The requirejs.org website [indicates it is best to use the dojo loader](http://requirejs.org/docs/dojo.html) until a [ticket is resolved](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15616) - but that ticket appears to be resolved and is now closed.

I am encountering errors such as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711102/using-dojo-1-8-with-requirejs)  (duplicated below) only now with dojo 1.9.1.

Error:

> TypeError: _3.add is not a function
>   _3.add("dom-addeventlistener",!!document.addEventListener);

(I have an existing backbone app that uses requirejs and am simply trying to integrate in dojo charting).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the [source/SDK version](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.9.1/dojo-release-1.9.1-src.tar.gz) of the Dojo Toolkit. Built copies of AMD modules are not compatible between loaders.

Comment: Confirmed this worked for me too. Though the link goes to 1.9
http://download.dojotoolkit.org/ for all downloads