# Require.js and Dojo conflict

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs

I have a mobile application which is written with requirejs, backbone, and jQuery.
It has suddenly come to my attention that a new third part library is required for our map technology.
This map technology is built using Dojo which comes shipped with requirejs baked in.

Is there any simple way to run them both in parallel without conflicts?

Edit: The third party script is using a prebuilt version of application bundled with Dojo 1.9. I can not inject my application code into this as their built version has had the config injection stripped out.

Comment: you could check out the requirejs with dojo [link](http://requirejs.org/docs/dojo.html)

Comment: It will not work with a prebuilt version of dojo. You need the source version : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475515/using-requirejs-with-dojo-1-9-1. This might help as well : https://geonet.esri.com/thread/102952

Comment: @Philippe did you want to write up a proper answer so that when I test this out tomorrow I can award you best answer? It seems like it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work with a prebuilt version of dojo. You need the source version : see [Using requirejs with dojo 1.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475515/using-requirejs-with-dojo-1-9-1). This might help as well : http://geonet.esri.com/thread/102952